# progressbar no se incrementa durante el proceso sino al acabar el proceso

Tags: java, java-swing, progressbar

estoy haciendo un programa para repartir herencias equitativamente. Como a la hora de hacer los calculos tarda un poco, o mucho, dependiendo del numero de herederos y bienes a repartir,y quiero ponerle dos progressbar donde muestre el progreso de los calculos. Los progressbar se incrementan en las funciones `findCombinations` y `findCombinationsCombinations` respectivamente, que son dos funciones recursivas. Pero me encuentro con que los progressbar no se incrementan poco a poco durante el proceso sino que lo hacen al final del proceso y lo hacen los dos de golpe. Y no entiendo por que ya que yo los incremento en las funciones que he indicado anteriormente cada vez que hay un calculo satisfactorio. ¿como puedo solucionar esto y que los progressbar se incrementen en las funciones que he indicado?

```
public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static ArrayList<Bien> A = new ArrayList();
    public static int k;
    public static int nHerederos = 4;
    public static int numerodecombinaciones=0;
    public static int numerodecombinacionescombinaciones=0;
    
    public static long factorial(long numero)
    {
        long factorial=1;
        while ( numero!=0) {
        factorial=factorial*numero; numero--;
       }
        return factorial;
    }
    
    public static long nCombinaciones(long numero,long orden)
    {
        long nCombinaciones=factorial(numero)/(factorial(orden)*(factorial(numero-orden)));
        return nCombinaciones;
    }
    
    public static BigInteger factorialBI(BigInteger numero)
    {
        BigInteger factorial= BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        while ( numero!=BigInteger.valueOf(0)) {
        factorial=factorial.multiply(numero);
        numero=numero.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
        //System.out.println(numero);
       }
        return factorial;
    }
    
    public static BigInteger nCombinacionesBI(long numero,long orden)
    {
        
        BigInteger nCombinaciones=factorialBI(BigInteger.valueOf(numero)).divide((factorialBI(BigInteger.valueOf(orden)).multiply((factorialBI(BigInteger.valueOf(numero).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(orden)))))));
        return nCombinaciones;
    }
    
    public void findCombinations(ArrayList<Bien> A, int i, int k,
                                        Set<List<Bien>> subarrays,
                                        List<Bien> out)
            
            
    {
        // entrada inválida
        if (A.size() == 0 || k > A.size()) {
            return;
        }
 
        // caso base: el tamaño de la combinación es `k`
        if (k == 0) {
            
            subarrays.add(new ArrayList<>(out));
            numerodecombinaciones++;
            //System.out.println(numerodecombinaciones);
            jProgressBar1.setValue(numerodecombinaciones);
            return;
        }
        
        // comienza desde el siguiente índice hasta el último índice
        for (int j = i; j < A.size(); j++)
        {
            // agrega el elemento actual `A[j]` a la solución y repite para el siguiente índice
            // `j+1` con un elemento menos `k-1`
            out.add(A.get(j));
            findCombinations(A, j + 1, k - 1, subarrays, out);
            out.remove(out.size() - 1);        // retractarse
            
        }
    }
    
public void findCombinationsCombinations(List<List<Bien>> combinaciones, int i, int k,
                                        Set<List<List<Bien>>> subarrays,
                                        List<List<Bien>> out)
            
            
    {
        // entrada inválida
        if (combinaciones.size() == 0 || k > combinaciones.size()) {
            return;
        }
 
        // caso base: el tamaño de la combinación es `k`
        if (k == 0) {
            subarrays.add(new ArrayList<>(out));
            numerodecombinacionescombinaciones++;
            jProgressBar2.setValue(numerodecombinacionescombinaciones);
            return;
        }
 
        // comienza desde el siguiente índice hasta el último índice
        for (int j = i; j < combinaciones.size(); j++)
        {
            // agrega el elemento actual `A[j]` a la solución y repite para el siguiente índice
            // `j+1` con un elemento menos `k-1`
            out.add(combinaciones.get(j));
            
            findCombinationsCombinations(combinaciones, j + 1, k - 1, subarrays, out);
            out.remove(out.size() - 1);        // retractarse
        }
    }
    
public static List<List<Bien>> combinaciones = new ArrayList();
public static List<List<List<Bien>>> combinacionesCombinaciones = new ArrayList();

public  Set<List<Bien>> findCombinations(ArrayList<Bien> A, int k)
    {
        Set<List<Bien>> subarrays = new HashSet<>();
        findCombinations(A, 0, k, subarrays, new ArrayList<>());
        combinaciones.addAll(subarrays);
        return subarrays;
    }
public Set<List<List<Bien>>> findCombinationsCombinations(List<List<Bien>> combinaciones, int k)
    {
        Set<List<List<Bien>>> subarrays = new HashSet<>();
        findCombinationsCombinations(combinaciones, 0, k, subarrays, new ArrayList<>());
        combinacionesCombinaciones.addAll(subarrays);
        return subarrays;
    }

    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
}
    

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jProgressBar2 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 344, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jProgressBar2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(149, 149, 149)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(130, 130, 130)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jProgressBar2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(66, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Bien b1 = new Bien("revolta",1);
        Bien b2 = new Bien("bouzas",2);
        Bien b3 = new Bien("nazo",3);
        Bien b4 = new Bien("gradin",4);
        Bien b5 = new Bien("faro",5);
        Bien b6 = new Bien("niño de agre",6);
        Bien b7 = new Bien("gradin",7);
        Bien b8 = new Bien("faro",8);
        Bien b9 = new Bien("niño de agre",9);
        Bien b10 = new Bien("su outeiro",10);
        A.add(b1);A.add(b2);A.add(b3);A.add(b4);A.add(b5);
        //A.add(b6);//A.add(b7);A.add(b8);A.add(b9);A.add(b10);
        k =A.size();
        long nCombTotales= 0;
        BigInteger nCombCombTotales= BigInteger.valueOf(0);
        
        for(int l=1; l<=k;l++)
        {
            nCombTotales+=nCombinaciones(A.size(),l);
        }
                
        nCombCombTotales=nCombinacionesBI(nCombTotales,nHerederos);
        jProgressBar1.setMaximum((int)nCombTotales);
        jProgressBar2.setMaximum(nCombCombTotales.intValue());     
        
        int valorTotalBienes=0;
        for(Bien b:A)
        {
            valorTotalBienes+=b.getValor();
        }
        int mediaDeCadaArray=valorTotalBienes/nHerederos;
        
        for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
        {
            findCombinations(A,i);   
        }
        
        findCombinationsCombinations(combinaciones,nHerederos);
        for(List<List<Bien>> bien1:combinacionesCombinaciones)
        {
            for(List<Bien> bien2:bien1)
            {
                for(Bien bien3:bien2)
                {
                    System.out.print(bien3.getValor());
                }
            System.out.println("grupo de bienes"); 
            }
            System.out.println("combinacion");
        }
    
    }                                        

    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Frame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Tu codigo no compila, incluye la clase Bien apra tener un [mcve]

Comment: ademas si imprimes `System.out.println("Cominaciones totales:"+ nCombCombTotales);` veras que vale cero.